# What is the quickest way to verify whether the first 10 elements of a vector are non-zero in R?

Tags: r

Suppose we have a 300 x 1000 matrix. If there exists *any row* of this matrix such that the *first* 10 elements of the row are non-zero, then a condition is satisfied. What is the quickest way to write this code instead of doing it using for loops?

Comment: `any(rowSums(your_matrix[, 1:10] != 0) == 10)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`any(apply(m[, 1:10], MARGIN = 1, function(x) all(x != 0)))` should be pretty quick.